# How to reorder words based on their assigned probability in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe shown below (please note that this is only first 6 data of my dataframe. The dataframe has 161 rows):

```
> head(a)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  word     name   value
  <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>
1 amen     t_1   0.0168
2 pool     t_1   0.0153
3 gym      t_1   0.0150
4 yaletown t_1   0.0139
5 fals     t_1   0.0112
6 creek    t_1   0.0112
---  --- ----- --------
```

I want to plot this data for each name group and here is my code:

```
ggplot(a, aes(word, value, fill = factor(name))) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ name, scales = "free") +
  coord_flip()
```

The result is shown below:

[image]

This graph is good except that I want each graph to be sorted from high to low. for example for t_1, I want the word **amen** to be on top. How can I do this?

**DATA**

```
structure(list(word = c("amen", "pool", "gym", "yaletown", "fals", 
"creek", "concierg", "fals_creek", "seawal", "tub", "hot", "sauna", 
"hot_tub", "amen_includ", "citi", "indoor", "downtown", "offer", 
"centr", "indoor_pool", "pet", "rental", "updat", "laundri", 
"insuit", "quiet", "renov", "bright", "storag_locker", "face", 
"corner", "fireplac", "patio", "hous", "strata", "roof", "south", 
"paint", "pet_rental", "insuit_laundri", "mountain", "harbour", 
"stanlei", "stanlei_park", "english", "bai", "english_bai", "coal", 
"citi", "north", "coal_harbour", "concierg", "water", "vancouv", 
"shore", "north_shore", "luxuri", "offer", "enjoi", "shore_mountain", 
"master", "privat", "level", "bath", "patio", "ensuit", "main", 
"closet", "dine", "master_bedroom", "fireplac", "offer", "townhom", 
"garag", "size", "deck", "garden", "entertain", "famili", "hous", 
"school", "ubc", "secondari", "elementari", "centr", "commun", 
"close", "conveni", "line", "villag", "catchment", "polygon", 
"distanc", "canada", "pacif", "walk_distanc", "face", "canada_line", 
"oakridg", "vancouv", "bright", "centr", "river", "fit", "amen", 
"wall", "district", "central", "river_district", "vancouv", "meet", 
"commun", "amen_includ", "daili", "garden", "gold", "leed", "rang", 
"ga_rang", "heat", "pool", "custom", "design", "counter", "countertop", 
"quartz", "modern", "light", "tile", "cabinet", "top", "hardwood", 
"concret", "finish", "heat", "loft", "stone", "hardwood_floor", 
"stainless", "cabinetri", "wall", "stainless", "steel", "stainless_steel", 
"steel_applianc", "granit", "downtown", "lamin", "insuit", "skytrain", 
"countertop", "counter", "laundri", "lamin_floor", "close", "face", 
"bright", "central", "buyer", "transit", "storag_locker"), name = c("t_1", 
"t_1", "t_1", "t_1", "t_1", "t_1", "t_1", "t_1", "t_1", "t_1", 
"t_1", "t_1", "t_1", "t_1", "t_1", "t_1", "t_1", "t_1", "t_1", 
"t_1", "t_2", "t_2", "t_2", "t_2", "t_2", "t_2", "t_2", "t_2", 
"t_2", "t_2", "t_2", "t_2", "t_2", "t_2", "t_2", "t_2", "t_2", 
"t_2", "t_2", "t_2", "t_3", "t_3", "t_3", "t_3", "t_3", "t_3", 
"t_3", "t_3", "t_3", "t_3", "t_3", "t_3", "t_3", "t_3", "t_3", 
"t_3", "t_3", "t_3", "t_3", "t_3", "t_4", "t_4", "t_4", "t_4", 
"t_4", "t_4", "t_4", "t_4", "t_4", "t_4", "t_4", "t_4", "t_4", 
"t_4", "t_4", "t_4", "t_4", "t_4", "t_4", "t_4", "t_5", "t_5", 
"t_5", "t_5", "t_5", "t_5", "t_5", "t_5", "t_5", "t_5", "t_5", 
"t_5", "t_5", "t_5", "t_5", "t_5", "t_5", "t_5", "t_5", "t_5", 
"t_5", "t_6", "t_6", "t_6", "t_6", "t_6", "t_6", "t_6", "t_6", 
"t_6", "t_6", "t_6", "t_6", "t_6", "t_6", "t_6", "t_6", "t_6", 
"t_6", "t_6", "t_6", "t_7", "t_7", "t_7", "t_7", "t_7", "t_7", 
"t_7", "t_7", "t_7", "t_7", "t_7", "t_7", "t_7", "t_7", "t_7", 
"t_7", "t_7", "t_7", "t_7", "t_7", "t_8", "t_8", "t_8", "t_8", 
"t_8", "t_8", "t_8", "t_8", "t_8", "t_8", "t_8", "t_8", "t_8", 
"t_8", "t_8", "t_8", "t_8", "t_8", "t_8", "t_8"), value = c(0.0168220200995057, 
0.0153161615392215, 0.0149904123428906, 0.0138688207986376, 0.0112433212880903, 
0.0112374695061203, 0.01112823624268, 0.0110833725809099, 0.0101256309318173, 
0.00999689172847693, 0.00971405559992615, 0.00946633016319547, 
0.00937855343364523, 0.00916203750075464, 0.00908986552312444, 
0.00811651912211177, 0.00672769620122796, 0.00660870996783763, 
0.0057953122740054, 0.00572899207834522, 0.0138658083101884, 
0.0137837795637179, 0.010485360495114, 0.0091757787532163, 0.00819431199720066, 
0.00798132507654038, 0.00756830314255726, 0.00734955981863588, 
0.0068415572308448, 0.00680557971046299, 0.00665591322567468, 
0.00659547099143325, 0.0065925927898027, 0.00653215055556127, 
0.00651632044659328, 0.00646019551479766, 0.00623857398924574, 
0.00599680505228001, 0.00596082753189821, 0.00569171567944231, 
0.0186241974972874, 0.0147573323720616, 0.0135304193706392, 0.0131429731596637, 
0.0128808771934156, 0.0128618847320933, 0.0125200204282914, 0.0124706400288533, 
0.0124288566139442, 0.0122617229543077, 0.0119084631737125, 0.0107879079556951, 
0.0103320888839593, 0.0098914637812813, 0.00987247131995897, 
0.00924951858858663, 0.00903680302177657, 0.00830369401473473, 
0.007889658357908, 0.00771492771374258, 0.0189024481694971, 0.0180269566047608, 
0.0160150330924837, 0.0141518699853569, 0.013476351424265, 0.0128983806698291, 
0.0127203559226821, 0.0107181871910707, 0.0100816877526412, 0.00948176874170768, 
0.00909645490541704, 0.00737717481310755, 0.00708697008830637, 
0.00698454489131772, 0.0067918879731724, 0.00671628842301411, 
0.00664312756802222, 0.00659435366469429, 0.00656265062753114, 
0.00626269112206438, 0.0244598442695631, 0.0219542590218986, 
0.014506306535134, 0.0140648189743327, 0.0114732296563822, 0.0111922830267814, 
0.00977034906472007, 0.00792412835591466, 0.00774065300597126, 
0.00768331695911395, 0.00750557521385629, 0.0069723499780833, 
0.0067888746281399, 0.00666273532505382, 0.00659966567351077, 
0.00654232962665346, 0.00650219439385335, 0.00632445264859568, 
0.00621551415956679, 0.0061811125314524, 0.0061811125314524, 
0.0318859345137425, 0.0240809552302102, 0.0145728663053292, 0.0145503085617352, 
0.0133209115358609, 0.0118433793304523, 0.0113809455867748, 0.0106590977917661, 
0.010591424560984, 0.0102756161506677, 0.0101289908173065, 0.0100049232275394, 
0.00893343040682327, 0.00888831491963522, 0.00884319943244717, 
0.00866273748369498, 0.00809879389384439, 0.00778298548352805, 
0.00778298548352805, 0.00778298548352805, 0.0105073596303114, 
0.0104255592614531, 0.01040715417846, 0.00863004116501312, 0.00785907268852352, 
0.00765252675715628, 0.00763616668338462, 0.0074480258350105, 
0.00686928822533793, 0.00684270310545898, 0.00677521780115087, 
0.00662797713720591, 0.00607991466585521, 0.00596743915867503, 
0.00596334914023211, 0.00567704784922801, 0.00560342751725553, 
0.00560138250803408, 0.00558706744348387, 0.00558706744348387, 
0.0211985535498137, 0.0193575351827745, 0.0189303064930188, 0.0173450631968202, 
0.0141520908839095, 0.00979829324949158, 0.00938792885012101, 
0.00923896095171936, 0.00923052880652682, 0.00842666429817077, 
0.00802754275905693, 0.00795165345232402, 0.00788981772091202, 
0.00777457840328056, 0.00768182480616255, 0.00744291402570708, 
0.00740356401480853, 0.00717870680967398, 0.00694822817441105, 
0.00671774953914813)), row.names = c(NA, -161L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This trick using ordered factors will get you most of the way there:

```
df <- a %>% 
  arrange(name, value) %>% 
  mutate(word = factor(word, unique(word), ordered = T))

ggplot(df, aes(word, value, fill = factor(name))) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ name, scales = "free") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

However, because some `word`s appear under multiple `name`s, for some of them the ordering is off. Another solution would be to give each row a unique name, then edit the labeling in `scale_x_discrete` with `gsub`.

```
df <- a %>% 
  mutate(combo_name = paste(name, word)) %>% 
  arrange(name, value) %>% 
  mutate(combo_name = factor(combo_name, combo_name, ordered = T))

ggplot(df, aes(combo_name, value, fill = factor(name))) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ name, scales = "free") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) gsub('.* ', '', x)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The package `tidytext` has a function [`reorder_within`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidytext/versions/0.3.0/topics/reorder_within) specifically for this type of problem. The default aggregation is to take the mean of `value` within `name`, but since there is only one value per `name`, `word` pair this returns the same as the max function.

```
library(tidytext)

ggplot(a, aes(reorder_within(word, value, name), value, fill = factor(name))) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ name, scales = "free") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_reordered()
```

Note the use of `scale_x_reordered()` from the same package.

Comment: This solution is easy and elegant; however, the name of words are changing for some reason. Not sure why this is happening

Comment: Are you using `scale_x_reordered` too?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I haven't used `scale_x_reordered`, now it's working. Thanks for your simple and elegant solution

Answer (score 2):

You could use `fct_reorder` in [`forcats`package](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_reorder.html).
To handle the order in each facet, the factor is composed by `paste(name,word)` :

```
ggplot(a, aes(fct_reorder(.f=paste(name,word),.x=value), value, fill = factor(name))) +
  xlab(label =  "word")+
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ name, scales = "free") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]